# Wiper arm nut loosens

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, windshield-wipers

2010 Silverado 1500:

The nut on the left wiper arm loosens on occasion. The nut doesn't come off, but the wiper doesn't move when the nut is loose.

I can easily tighten the nut with a ratchet when it happens, temporarily solving the issue. But it will inevitably loosen again.

How can I prevent the nut from loosening in the future?

[image]

Comment: Remove the nut, clean threads of corrosion, examine if the wiper and stud serrations are corroded and filled with ground wiper debris. Pot metal casting allows the wiper base to fit tightly over the serrated stud shaft, but is softer than aluminum and easily wears. If the wiper base fits snug on the shaft, a dose of blue loctite will seal and bond threads, preventing the nut from loosening and still allow nut removal at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some light type [Loctite 222](https://www.henkel-adhesives.com/us/en/product/threadlockers/loctite_2220.html) (no affiliation). It will hold the nut in place without the issue of it being hard to remove if you ever need to.